# Session doesn't get stored permanently Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.5

I am creating a small blog-esque site. This site has basically 3 permission levels: Admin (can edit/remove any post AND create a user), a user (can upload posts and pictures) and a guest (no account needed, can just browse the posts).

I am using Laravel 5.5 to create this site.

When someone logs in, after being authenticated, I store their username and user type (admin/user) in a session and after login, they are redirected to their respective pages, as shown in the below code.

I overrided the 'authenticated' method in the AuthenticatesUsers trait:

LoginController.php

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $type = $user->toArray()['type'];//get user type (admin/user)
    $username = $user->toArray()['username'];
    $request->session()->put('type', $type);
    $request->session()->put('username', $username);
    if ( $type == 'admin' ) {
        return redirect()->route('admin_home');
    }

    return redirect()->route('user_home');
}
```

The above code works and my user is redirected upon successful login.

However, if my user accesses the site home (localhost:8000/) I want the user to see the admin home page or user home page (localhost:8000/ just shows the homepage for a not logged in guest)

I did that using the following codes:

Web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'ContentController@publicHome');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/user/home', 'ContentController@userHome')->name('user_home');
    Route::get('/admin/home', 'ContentController@adminHome')->name('admin_home');
});
```

Filtering whether user is logged in or just a guest:

ContentController - publicHome function

```
public function publicHome(Request $request){
    $data = [];
    $data['home'] = 1;
    if($request->session()->has('type')){
        switch ($request->session()->pull('type')){
            case 'admin':
                return redirect()->route('admin_home');
            case 'user':
                return redirect()->route('user_home');
        }
    }
    return view('public.home', $data);
}
```

ContentController - userHome function

```
public function userHome(Request $request){
    $data = [];
    $data['username'] = $this->getUsername($request);
    $data['type'] = $this->getUserType($request);
//  dd($data); explanation for this line below
    return view('user.home', $data);
}
```

ContentController - adminHome function

```
public function adminHome(Request $request){
    $data = [];
    $data['username'] = $this->getUsername($request);
    $data['type'] = $this->getUserType($request);
    //dd($data);
    return view('admin.home', $data);
}
```

ContentController - getUsername & getUserType functions

```
public function getUsername(Request $request){
        return $request->session()->has('username') ? $request->session()->pull('username') : 'username not set';
}

public function getUserType(Request $request){
        return $request->session()->has('type') ? $request->session()->pull('type') : 'user type not set';
}
```

I used the dump and die function to see the `$data[]` array before loading the view

Right after successful login:

```
array:2 [▼
  "username" => "testAdmin"
   "type" => "admin"
] //works correctly, session variables seem to be set
```

So when I type in `localhost:8000/` I expect to be redirected to `/admin/home` (or `/user/home` depending on login) but I just get sent to localhost:8000/ as if I am not logged in. So now when I manually type in `/admin/home` I get the following dump and die output:

```
array:2 [▼
  "username" => "username not set"
  "type" => "user type not set"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `$request->session()->pull('username')` it fetches the data i.e. username from session and deletes it at the same time.

Instead, you can use laravel's helper method `session()` to get data without deleting it. So now you can use `session('username')` to get the username.

For more info refer : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session

**Some Suggestions:**

1. You could have used laravel's internal Auth library to build the login system which already has lot many features you don't need to code again. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication
2. You can also have multi-user authentication (admin & regular user). Refer this link if you want to implement so: https://scotch.io/tutorials/user-authorization-in-laravel-54-with-spatie-laravel-permission

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the problem. I clearly need to read up more on the documentation. Thanks for your suggestion as well. One last question: Are all session variables cleared once the user logs out? I'm using the `logout` route that comes with the Laravel Auth Scaffolding

Comment: @user3536523 **Never tried it**. In case if you want to manually delete all your session data you can flush it `$request->session()->flush()`;